# Refactoring the Spring Boot application such that code changes not required for repetitive future enhancements

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

My current application fetches data for 3 journeys. The application will be updated with multiple journeys going forward which might extend upto 16 journeys in a course of time.
We make use of a SQL query to fetch data for the 3 journeys. Retrieve values for each journey based on calculations, map it to a model and then return the list of objects as API response.
We also have constant values for each journeys declared in the application.properties files.

```
ArrayList<Journey> journeyList = new ArrayList<>();
Journey journey1 = getJourney1(); // method to retrieve and map journey1 values to Journey model
Journey journey2 = getJourney2(); // method to retrieve and map journey2 values to Journey model
Journey journey3 = getJourney3();
return journeyList;
```

Currently if a new journey is to be added, code changes are required in the following,

1. Sql query
2. Object creation for each new journey
3. New constants to be updated for the additional journeys in the application.properties files.

Kindly help to advise on how the application can be refracted in such a way that any new journey to be added does not require any additional code changes. This will help us to avoid multiple deployments and repetitive work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the design pattern of spring.factories to create a file similar to journey.factories.

```
com.example.Journey=com.example.JourneyType1,\
                com.example.JourneyType2
```

Define the Journey interface and its implementations:

```
public interface Journey {
void fetchData();
// other methods
}

public class JourneyType1 implements Journey {
// Implement the above methods
}
```

Use the JourneyLoader:

```
public void handleJourneys() {
JourneyLoader loader = new JourneyLoader();
List<Journey> journeys = loader.loadJourneys();

for (Journey journey : journeys) {
    journey.fetchData();
    // other operations
}
}
```